# How to convert a large number into ranges of 100 of start and end properties of objects using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, take a number like 367 and create an array of objects like this:

```
     var pages = [
                   {page1: {start: 1, end: 99}},
                   {page2: {start: 100, end: 199}}, 
                   {page3: {start: 200, end:299}}, 
                   {page4: {start: 300, end: 367}}
                 ];
```

Comment: Why are you indexing your pages twice (in the array index as well as the array item)? Also, your first page has a range of 99 values and the others have a range of 100 - is this intended?

Comment: Thanks Michael for bringing up a good question, but yes, its intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var num = 367;
var pages = [];
for (i = 0; i <= num / 100; i++) {
    var a = i == 0 ? 1 : i * 100;
    var b = (i + 1) * 100 - 1;
    if (b > num) b = num;
    var x = {};
    x['page' + (i + 1)] = {start: a, end: b};
    pages.push(x);
}
```

And I tested it and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

One dirty approach (not tested)

```
var myNum = 367;
var cnt = Math.ceil(myNum / 100);
var pages = [];

for(i = 1;i == cnt;++i){
    var newPage = {};
    newPage['page'+i] = { start:(i-1)*100, end:(99+(i-1)*100) };

    if(i == 1){
        newPage['page'+i].start = 1;
    }
    if(i == cnt){
        newPage['page'+i].end = myNum % 100;
    }

    pages.push( newPage );
}
```

**Update** according to comment

Comment: This misses out `100`, `200`, `300` and starts from `page0` not `page1`

Answer (score 0):

```
function gen_pages(x) {
    var i = 100,
        j = 199,
        k = 2,
        o,
        pages = [];

    if (x <= 99) { // if we have less than 100, just do the first page
        pages.push({page1: {start: 1, end: x}});
    } else {
        pages.push({page1: {start: 1, end: 99}}); // first page is a special case
        while (i <= x) {
            if (j > x) { // reduce j if we're getting to the end
                j = x;
            }
            o = {};
            o['page' + k] = {start: i, end: j};
            pages.push(o);
            i += 100;
            j += 100;
            k += 1;
        }
    }
    return pages;
}

gen_pages(367); /*
[
    {"page1": {"start":   1, "end":  99}},
    {"page2": {"start": 100, "end": 199}},
    {"page3": {"start": 200, "end": 299}},
    {"page4": {"start": 300, "end": 367}}
]
*/
```